Proper way to print strings with inserted vector values in R
Let v be a vector storing some values, e.g 1,2,3. I want to print a message like "Values are: 1,2,3". In Python it would be as simple as printing f-string f"Values are: {v}", however in R it seems weirdly complicated. I tried:
v = c(1,2,3)
s = "Values are: "

paste(s,v)                           # "Values are:  1" "Values are:  2" "Values are:  3"
paste0(s,v)                          # "Values are:  1" "Values are:  2" "Values are:  3"
paste(s,v, sep = ",", collapse = "") # "Values are: ,1Values are: ,2Values are: ,3"
cat(s,v)                             # Values are:  1 2 3
cat(s,paste(v, sep = ","))           # Values are:  1 2 3
cat(s, cat(v))                       # 1 2 3Values are: (this one is weird)
paste(s, paste(v, sep= ","))         # "Values are:  1" "Values are:  2" "Values are:  3"

What is the proper way to do it???

cat(s, paste(v, collapse=","))

You almost had it:
cat(s, paste(v, collapse=","))
# Values are:  1,2,3


sprintf("%s%s", s, paste(v, collapse = ","))
# [1] "Values are: 1,2,3"

# or 
paste0(s, paste(v, collapse = ","))
# [1] "Values are: 1,2,3"

# or
library(glue)
glue::glue("{s}{v_collapsed}", v_collapsed = paste(v, collapse = ","))

